# mysql join 3 tables and count 2

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (users, answers and questions) and need to count the total amount of users divided by registered and not registered that have finish all the answers of each day.

So I would have something like:

Total users completed day 1, total registered users completed day 1

Total users completed day 2, total registered users completed day 2

Total users completed day 3, total registered users completed day 3

Table structures are:

```
Users
Id, registered

Answers
id, user_id, question_id

Questions
id, day
```

And this is the query that i am working with.

```
select 
  a.user_id, a.question_id ,
  count(distinct q.day) as day
from answers a
left join questions q on q.id = a.question_id
left join users u on u.registered IS NOT NULL
group by u.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT q.day, COUNT(u.id) AS users, COUNT(u.registered) AS reg_users
  FROM answers a
  JOIN questions q ON q.id = a.question_id
  JOIN users u ON u.id = a.user_id
  GROUP BY q.day
```

### EDIT

If you have multiple occurrence of users in a day, you should try something like this:

```
SELECT day, COUNT(id) AS users, COUNT(registered) AS reg_users
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT q.day, u.id, u.registered
           FROM answers a
           JOIN questions q ON q.id = a.question_id
           JOIN users u ON u.id = a.user_id ) qwert
  GROUP BY day
```

### EDIT

Counting users, who have answered at least 15 questions the given day:

```
SELECT day, user_id, COUNT( DISTINCT question_id) AS users_15
  FROM answers a
  JOIN questions q ON q.id = a.question_id
  GROUP BY day, user_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT question_id) >= 15
```

Comment: Got it, i was missing count(distinct u.users)

Comment: How can I also count the users that have answered 15 questions?

Comment: I think something is missing, The query isnt returning the users totals...

Comment: done but something is missing still, its like isnt grouping/counting the users totals